# How to view the enqueued messages of a Queue|Topic of ActiveMQ using Hawtio Web Console

Tags: activemq-classic, hawtio

I have embedded the Active MQ + Hawtio jar files in the middleware integration tool Mulesoft and when deployed the tool, the Hawtio console runs on localhost:8080.

I tried two ways of enqueuing messages into a queue. The queues are created via Hawtio Conolse. Given below are the two ways I put messages into the queue. Both the ways work !

1. Via Mulesoft JMS publish connectors
2. Via Hawtio console directly using the "send" button
   [image]

But there is only one way to retrieve the enqueued messages in the queues as far as I know i.e. via the same Mulesoft JMS Listener connector. I didn't learn other ways to retrieve.

**Question:**

Is there any way to view the stored messages directly in the Hawtio Console ? or go to some system directories of my machine to view the stored data ?

I can see few list of operations available in the Console too, but I tried to execute them and none of them worked. Also I couldn't either find better documentation to understand these given operations. The response always return **[ ]** when I hit "execute"

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Hawtio is a queue browser, that is another kind of JMS client, so you can't see messages if they are in any client's prefetch buffer (i.e. Mulesoft JMS Listener). Instead, if there are no other consumers connected, then you should be able to see all unacknowledged messages using the `browse()` and related management operations.